# In discord.py how can I delete multiple messages via ID?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a command that deletes multiple messages at once via the message ID.

Here's my (very basic) code so far:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def delete(ctx, msg:discord.Message):
    await msg.delete()
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

The problem with it is that it only deletes the first message. I tried adding something like ,*, before the msg:discord.Message, using for loops and something like message.content.split but so far, everything I tried has been unsuccessful, I'm pretty new to discord bots and python in general.

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were heading in a good direction, here's how you'd do it:

```py
async def delete(ctx, *messages: discord.Message):
    for message in messages:
        await message.delete()
```

Note: This will not work for messages that aren't in the same channel where the command was invoked